# Suitable Clustering Approach

Tags: data-science, cluster-analysis

I've got a total of 9 sensors in the ground, which measure the water content of the soil. 1-3 are in a depth of 1m, 4-6 are in a depth of 2m and sensors 7-9 are in a depth of 3m.

My dataset also contains the precipiation of the location. It is hourly data:

| Time | Sensor-ID | Precipitation | Soil Water Content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 11:00 | 1 | 74 | 120 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00 | 2 | 74 | 100 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00 | 3 | 74 | 110 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 11:00 | 9 | 74 | 30 |

The goal now is to find out if the different ground / soil depths behave differently regarding the water content after raining (over time).

I thought about a clustering method to find out if the sensors can be clustered based on the data and confirm this. Since I'm not very experienced in data science, would that be the right approach and is it even possible to analyse it with clustering?

Answer (score 1):

For clustering, you can add a new column with three new classes to your data - for 1-3 sensors : Class 1,  for 4-6 sensors : Class 2, for 7-9 sensors : Class 3 and perform your analysis using the new classes. Either can be done using Python, Power BI or Excel.

You should start by analyzing different variables w.r.t to the sensors at different ground depths: Use univariate, Bi-Variate and Multi-Variate plots to derive your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I don't want to include only one point in time for clustering, would be time series clustering a suitable approach? to find out the similarity of the sensors.